# How to leverage DCOM garbage collector with custom marshaling? (IMarshal)

Tags: com, dcom

I'm working on a multi-tenant COM server that exposes classes with different interfaces in a hierarchy. Some of the classes implement [IMarshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-imarshal) for more efficient custom marshaling using shared-memory for zero-copy exchange of immutable data buffers (based on "Inside COM+: Base Services" book). This works nicely but comes at the downside of losing automatic stub cleanup by the DCOM garbage collector if the client crashes or leaks handles. I've grown quite found of using [COMGLB_FAST_RUNDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/archive/blogs/distributedservices/com-server-cleanup-now-you-can-opt-for-a-fast-rundown) for fast stub cleanup after client crashes, and would very much like automatic cleanup also for `IMarshal` classes if possible.

I've already tried implementing `IExternalConnection` to intercept reference release events from the client-side proxy. However, this interface does *not* seem to be called for classes that also implement IMarshal. `IFastRundown` is similarly also not called for classes implementing IMarshal.

I'm reluctant to implementing my own watchdog to detect & handle client process crashes, since that would require manual bookkeeping of references held by each client for each object instance that implements IMarshal. This sounds like a lot of bookkeeping to me. Detecting the client process PID is furthermore inconvenient, especially if it needs to be done separately for each object reference due to the multi-tenant architecture. Leveraging the DCOM garbage collector would make everything much easier.

Any suggestions for **how to enable the DCOM garbage collector also for classes implementing IMarshal**?

I guess what I'm hoping for is some form of per-object event mechanism for being notified when client references are released that also sends an event if the client crashes.

Small reproducer project: https://github.com/forderud/SharedMemMarshal

Comment: I blundered into the [IFastRundown interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ifastrundown) while reading the docs.  No idea if it fixes your problem, but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @HansPassant. Unfortunately, IFastRundown is similarly also not called for classes implementing IMarshal

Comment: Unless you have disabled the pings, you still should benefit from automatic cleanup after some minutes (of not marshaling/unmarshaling).

Comment: Yes, all COM classes that are _not_ implementing IMarshal are still cleaned up automatically after a client crash. However, this cleanup does not seem to be triggered by classes implementing IMarshal.

Comment: Have you waited sufficient time? Otherwise how do you implement your IMarshal? Do you reuse the standard one in any way? Do you have a small reproducing project?

Comment: Cleanup happens within a few seconds when using `COMGLB_FAST_RUNDOWN` so there's no need for waiting long. You'll find a reproducer project at https://github.com/forderud/SharedMemMarshal . Any suggestions for improvements are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself since I just found a solution to this problem.

It's possible to introduce an **extra COM object for maintaining references from the client-side proxy back to the server**.

The https://github.com/forderud/SharedMemMarshal project have been updated to do just this through a tiny RefOwner class that is marshalled using `CoMarshalInterface`/`CoUnmarshalInterface` from the server to the proxy. This both simplifies the impl. as well as hardening it to better cope with reference leaks and client process crashes.